# VisualStudioCode IDE でブートローダーの書き込みが完了しない

Tags: spresense

Visual Studio Code IDEで開発環境を構築しており、ブートローダーの書き込みで壁にあたっております。

Versionはそれぞれ下記をインストール、ダウンロードしています。
VS Code: 1.73.1
Spresense VSCode IDE: 1.3.200
Spresense SDK: 2.6.0

この環境でVS Code上でF1押下、Spresense: ブートローダの書き込みを選択し、
ダウンロードしたspresense-binaries-v2.4.0.zipを指定したところ、
下記のメッセージがターミナル上に表示され、30分ほど放置しても進捗が見られません。

```
Install C:/msys64/home/USER/spresense/firmware/spresense/AESM.espk
Command not found: rrr
updater# install -b 115200
|0%-----------------------------50%------------------------------100%|
##Not ACK, Not NAK
############################################################Not ACK, Not NAK
##Not ACK, Not NAK
###Not ACK, Not NAK
##Not ACK, Not NAK
#

Not ACK, Not NAK
Not ACK, Not NAK
```

<中略>

```
Command not found: XXXi||JPp,Xm
Command not found: _c
Command not found: d>Tdo:NB
updater# ph3g50+<&JQi0*_je-ua0'`V=ZQ6ycph3g5*0rpGhhhx3``)=f'U+?F:VhEEE22O   Nx3`YZU)=f'U+?
Command not found: ph3g5*=:Hjk5S&rVinstall
```

上記まで進み、ここでターミナル画面が先に進まなくなっております。

基板の問題かどうかを確認するため、下記を行い、Arduino IDE では書き込みができたため、
基板は正常のように思います。

・リカバリツールを実施し、リカバリ後に再実施
⇒上記症状のまま変わらず

・SDKの過去バージョン2.5.1を指定してgit cloneして環境を再構築して実施
⇒上記症状のまま変わらず

・Arduino IDE 環境でブートローダーを書き込む
⇒Command not found: rrrの表示はされたものの、以降の書き込みは実施され、
　プログラムの書き込み、実行まで可能

解決の糸口がつかめない状況のため、何かアドバイスを頂けますと幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

Windows10とかでSilicon labの最新CP210xドライバーを使って発生してますかね？
https://www.silabs.com/developers/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers?tab=downloads

自分の環境は、ドライバーが古い（10.1 2021/01/08）のだったせいか、特に問題はありませんでしたが、最新のSiliconlabのドライバー（11.2 2022/10/21）をインストールすると、指摘の症状がでるようです。
何か問題があるようなので、前のVersionに落としたらよいと思います。
ただし初めて環境だと手持ちに古いVersionがないかもしれません。silconlab本家で探したが見つからなかったのですが、spresenseのガイドの方をみたら、11.1のものが用意されているようです。
（前に記載なかったように思いますので、履歴とかに書いてほしいですが・・）
https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-hw-design-files/raw/master/misc/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers/CP210x_Universal_Windows_Driver-v11.1.0.zip

こちらで、この現象が出なくなるようです。

注意として、ドライバーの11.2をインストールした場合、ドライバーの更新で11.1を入れても現象が消えず、自分の古いバージョンでも試しても変わらなかったので少し手間がかかりました。最終的に該当INFファイル、PNFファイルをいったん削除して対応しました。
以下の情報などが参考になりました。
https://www.ipentec.com/document/windows-delete-device-driver-in-driver-store

補足：
ドライバー11.2をインストールすると、ArduinoIDEでもいままで見たことのないエラーメッセージが出力されました。いわれるようにこちらはブートローダーを書き込むことはできましたが、これらを見ると11.2は利用しないほうがよさそうです。